# UTF-8 line breaks show up in phpMyAdmin but not on webpage

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I have a MySql table originally encoded in `latin1_swedish_ci`. Since my app uses unicode characters, I updated the column that stores utf8 data to use `utf8_unicode_ci` collation and also the table collation is changed to `utf8_unicode_ci` (all other columns which do not deal with utf_8 are left untouched in `latin1_swedish_ci` collation).

The input comes as an XML with utf-8 characters like bullets - and since PHP's DomDocument's loadXML() function needs utf-8 encoding of the input, I am encoding the XML before parsing as

```
$doc->loadXML(utf8_encode($Input));
```

Now, before inserting the utf-8 data in the table column, I am using PHP's `utf8_decode()` function so that it stores data properly. (if I don't do this, the bullet point characters are showing as junk characters when I display on a webpage).

The problem is with the line break characters `&#x0D;` which do not show a line break in the web page I am echoing the output to but when I view the record in phpMyAdmin, the line breaks showup (using firebug, I can see `<br>` tags with in the text).

What am I doing wrong? I tried using the following meta tag to set the encoding for my html page but that did not work either.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you use nl2br()?

```
echo nl2br($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're forgetting to use [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to turn newlines into line breaks.